# How do I avoid losing text and formatting when generating a document using conga composer?

Tags: formatting, conga

I use conga composer to generate agreements.  However, some of the formatting is lost in the process of generating the agreement from the template.  There doesn't seem to be a pattern to the lost formatting.  I also lose all section labels.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you'll get a much better answer, and more quickly, from Conga's own AWESOME [support](http://www.congamerge.com/support).

Comment: I've run into similar issues with conga, typically due to limitations of microsofts merge ability.  Conga support is VERY helpful in figuring out whether that's the case, and if so, how to work around the issue.